# Insert clause SQL and not specyfing last attribute

Tags: sql, syntax, insert

I am wondering, if there are any rules on the INSERT clause in SQL on Oracle.

Specifically, I have the following:

```
INSERT INTO Users ("Login","Birthday","Email") VALUES ("User1","somedate","asd@asd.com");
```

And this:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ("User1","somedate","asd@asd.com");
```

My question is: in the second statement, do I always need to input right number of attributes, or can I omit the last one? Like that:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ("User1","somedate");
```

Comment: @marc_s, thanks for quick answer!

Comment: Why don't you simply try #2 and check the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **don't explicitly specify** the columns you want to insert into, then you ***MUST ALWAYS*** supply ***ALL*** columns of the table, and **in the right order!**

For that reason, I would always prefer approach #1 - explicitly define the columns you want to insert into.

First of all, if you add another column to the table, your INSERT statements will still work (as long as it's not a `NOT NULL` column that requires input).

Secondly, you can define the order in which you insert the values into the columns - that can be quite helpful at times.

Answer (score 1):

In a word - yes.

An `insert` statement has two variants:

1. The first one in your post, where you specify the column names and match the value list to it.
2. The second one in your post, where you omit the column list. Here, the list implicitly contains all the columns in the table, in the order they were defined.

In both cases, if the number of values does not match the number of columns (even if it's implicitly defined), you'd get an error.